# Flutter animation(fade in and scaling) with words in a sentence

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want to create a flutter animation where there are three words in a sentence, the first one (COME) fades in and stays, followed by the other word that fades(HAVE) in too then, the final one (FUN)fades in and then its font is increased by 6, all words stay before moving on to the next screen. I tried the Animated kit and it did not work out well for me. It does everthing but I somehow cannot delay one animation after the other. I cannot also have a fade-in and scale animated text at the same time on the last word.I am looking into using an animation controller and tween but cannot do a fade in and scale at the same time.

```
       Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      AnimatedTextKit(animatedTexts: [
                        FadeAnimatedText(
                          'COME',
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18.0.sp,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                              color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ], isRepeatingAnimation: false),
                      AnimatedTextKit(
                        animatedTexts: [
                          FadeAnimatedText(
                            'HAVE',
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 18.0.sp,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ],
                        isRepeatingAnimation: false,
                      ),
                      AnimatedTextKit(
                        animatedTexts: [
                          ScaleAnimatedText(
                            'FUN',
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 24.0.sp,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                        isRepeatingAnimation: false,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that you've tried so far?

Comment: I have added part of the code of what i tried to use